# Attach "quick replies" to every message on supported channels - NodeJS bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

what is the easiest way to attach "quick replies" to every possible message?

I'm developing a bot, which it's main platform is FB, and i want to use quick replies.
the solution i see right now, is creating functions for all prompts etc, and reconstruct it with "sourceEvent".

is there a better way?

Comment: [BotFramework] tag in your question is a little bit confusing. Is this question related to Microsoft Bot Framework? If yes then I have a solution if no then remove the tag please  :)

Comment: @JustShadow yes it is! waiting to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Bot Framework library there is a file named [ChatConnector](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts#L453) where we have a such function which handles incoming messages:

```
 private dispatch(messages: IMessage|IMessage[], res: IWebResponse)
```

There after preparing the message, this method is called:
`this.handler([msg]);`
So I suggest you to edit the `handler` function there to send quick replies, or create another function and pass the message to it before or after sending it to `this.handler`.
Yes, actually this is a little bit hacky method, but I believe this should work.

Comment: This is NodeJS code taken from Microsoft's BotBuilder:   
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node